# How to change a math notation in multiple places in overleaf

Tags: overleaf

When using Overleaf for compiling, I can see whenever I select a math notation like $i$ here, the system will highlight the same notation in multiple places like in the screenshot.

I wonder if there are any shortcuts so that I could select and change them to another notation $k$ really quickly.

I know one way is to press "Ctrl" on my keyboard and use mouse cursor to select them one-by-one, but that is too slow. I have 100+ $i$'s like this...

Sorry if I asked this question in a wrong place, but I did see there is an Overleaf tag.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Pure Overleaf questions are offtopic here, please ask the support of Overleaf ...

Comment: Can't you just search and replace (with regex for example)? Unrelated, but just because I spotted this in your picture: Don't use double `$$`, [use `\[...\]` to typeset display math](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503/47927).

Comment: @JasperHabicht Searching will also find $i$ appearing EVERYWHERE including i in "again" and "copies" I only want those appearing as symbols as highlighted by overleaf

Comment: That's why I suggested regex: `[^a-z](i)[^a-z]` for example would find all `i` where no letter comes before or after; `\$.?(i).?\$` would find all `i` somewhere between two `$` (but this would probably not work if you also have `$$` in your document).

Comment: ctrl alt right is supposed to work but it doesn't...? [overleaf - Keybinding for multiple selection in ShareLaTeX? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/551653/keybinding-for-multiple-selection-in-sharelatex) ■ [overleaf - How can I change a word (that occurs often) in the document all at once - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/581388/how-can-i-change-a-word-that-occurs-often-in-the-document-all-at-once) doesn't have anything either.